# Помогите верно задать переменную

Tags: php, переменные

Привет, есть примерно такая штука:

шаблоны HTML в папке **views**, что то типа:

```
<html>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<body>
    <?php foreach ($mytext as $key => $val) { ?>
        <h1>
            <?php echo $val; ?>
        </h1>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

и почему то не получается их вызвать через функцию, пишет что переменная не найдена:

```
<?php

function view($tmp) {
    include_once ('views/' . $tmp);
}

$mytext = array('hello', 'my', 'dear', 'friend');
view('test2.php');

?>
```

хотя если написать прямо:

```
<?php

$mytext = array('hello', 'my', 'dear', 'friend');
include_once ('views/test2.php');

?>
```

То всё отлично работает. Подскажите где ошибка. Я так понимаю что подключение идёт в функции где "не видны" общие переменные, и есть вероятно 2 пути, либо объявить   переменную(массив) "видным везде", либо как то обозначить функцию, чтобы в ней были видны "все" переменные с того места откуда она вызывается, подскажите как реализовать? (способ передавать в функцию ещё переменные кроме имени файла как бы не хотелось)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не буду объяснять:

```
function view($tmp) {
    global $mytext;
    include_once ('views/' . $tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно имеет смысл задать в функции view параметр $tmp как не обязательный?

```
function view($tmp = null) {

   if($tmp) {
        global $mytext;
        include_once ('views/' . $tmp);
    }
}
```